# Error 505 when access custom function using ajax in OpenCart

Tags: jquery, ajax, opencart2.x

First of all, sorry for my bad english.

I've an OpenCart site that access custom function on ajax request when chekcout. But the problem is, when ajax working on the URL it fails. I got  500 (Internal Server Error).

I've attach the screenshot here:

http://prntscr.com/bda3e6

When I'm accessing the URL manually via web browser it works fine. Currently I'm using OpenCart version 2.1.0.1.

Please help me what happens in this system,

Thanks,

Comment: Adminanto, May be did use wrong method, can you please share us your code which you try to get.

Comment: thanks for the reply,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had this problem myself, even though i couldn't find the reason for it in my case, when  changing from `POST` to `GET`, the problem 500 error disappeared!

```
 type:'POST'
```

Comment: well, you right about asking the ajax requested function.
The problem lay on there,

many thanks for replying.